# Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts-1

Can any body help me over this...?

Here is my line of code. I am using `struts 1.x` and I have included two JSP's into a single JSP. My code is as follows. I have debugged it and the request for "LeftMenu.do" is processed at server side and return the `actionForward succcesfuly` and then happend the below mentioned error... need your valuable feedback.

```
<%@ include file="AppHeader.jsp"%>

<jsp:include  page="/pages/LeftMenu.do" />


[9/17/15 3:03:31:764 VET] 0000001b servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet action in application PHMICBIPSEAR. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed.
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:161)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:644)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1006)
at com.ibm._jsp._BIPSAdminFindPolicies._jspService(_BIPSAdminFindPolicies.java:319)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:335)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:325)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)


[9/17/15 3:03:31:777 VET] 0000001b LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[9/17/15 3:03:31:796 VET] 0000001b servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /bipspages/BIPSAdminFindPolicies.jsp in application PHMICBIPSEAR. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed.
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:161)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:644)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1006)
at com.ibm._jsp._BIPSAdminFindPolicies._jspService(_BIPSAdminFindPolicies.java:319)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:335)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:325)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)



[9/17/15 3:03:31:807 VET] 0000001b LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[9/17/15 3:03:31:893 VET] 0000001b servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet action in application PHMICBIPSEAR. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed.
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:161)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:644)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1006)
at com.ibm._jsp._BIPSAdminFindPolicies._jspService(_BIPSAdminFindPolicies.java:319)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:335)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:325)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

[9/17/15 3:03:31:984 VET] 0000001b FfdcProvider  I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_6a066a06_15.09.17_03.03.31.90264035.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch 448
[9/17/15 3:03:31:992 VET] 0000001b LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[9/17/15 3:03:32:000 VET] 0000001b webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[action]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed.
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:161)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:644)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1006)
at com.ibm._jsp._BIPSAdminFindPolicies._jspService(_BIPSAdminFindPolicies.java:319)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:335)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:325)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)


[9/17/15 3:03:32:009 VET] 0000001b srt           W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setStatus WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.
[9/17/15 3:03:32:013 VET] 0000001b srt           W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addHeader WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

Comment: The post needs to be formatted. Anyways, please post the JSP file here? I  hope it's small one.

Answer (score 0):

"struts 1.x" -> there's your problem :-).

But more seriously, the *.do is probably mapped to the struts servlet, and you can't do a jsp:include with a struts controller request, since struts already completely renders the response.

In Struts, shouldn't it be the controller that forwards to the JSP, instead of the JSP that includes the controller?

See e.g:
http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-forwardaction-example/

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

```
<jsp:include  page="/pages/LeftMenu.do" />
```

Are you caling your controller here? you can include JSP response/HTML response here but you cannot do a GET call to the controller.

if it was, `<jsp:include  page="/pages/LeftMenu.jsp" />` , this makes sense. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue resolved by placing all the code of javascript in the end of JSP file.

Mirza Abdul Rehman